# How to add a node in Binary search tree?

Tags: data-structures, c++14, binary-search-tree

```
struct node {
    int data{};
    node *right{nullptr};
    node *left{nullptr};
};
```

```
class BTree {
private:
    node *root;
    void insert(node *sr, int num);

public:
    BTree();
    void buildTree(int num);
};
```

```
void BTree::insert(node *sr, int num) {
    if (sr == nullptr) {
        sr = new node;
        sr->data = num;
    } else {
        if (num < sr->data)
            insert(sr->left, num);
        else
            insert(sr->right, num);
    }
}
```

```
int main() {
    BTree tree;
    tree.buildTree(3);
    return 0;
}
```

I am using the above insert method to add a node to Binary Search Tree. But this method is unable to add the node , if i add a number as its root or first node the root remains nullptr.
How do i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

At the first root is nullptr , and I am sending root i.e the nullptr as the argument. As nullptr does refer to any node therefor the root is not getting updated by the operation in the method.

possible solution:
use pointer to pointer, so that address of the node can be passed and and changed.

directly acces the root to do changes.

PROTOTYPE

```
void insert(node **sr, int num);
```

BUILD TREE METHOD

```
void BTree::buildTree(int num) {
    insert(&root, num);
}
```

INSERT METHOD

```
void BTree::insert(node **sr, int num) {
  if (*sr == nullptr) {
    *sr = new node;
    (*sr)->data = num;
  } else {
    if (num < (*sr)->data)
      insert(&((*sr)->left), num);
    else
      insert(&((*sr)->right), num);
  }
}
```